# Check command for validity with data from other aggregate

Tags: web, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I am currently working on my first bigger DDD application. For now it works pretty well, but we are stuck with an issue since the early days that I cannot stop thinking about:

In some of our aggreagtes we keep references to another aggregate-root that is pretty essential for the whole application (based on their IDs, so there are no hard references - also the deletion is based on events/eventual consistency). Now when we create a new Entity "Entity1" we send a new CreateEntity1Command that contains the ID of the referenced aggregate-root.

Now how can I check if this referenced ID is a valid one? Right now we check it by reading from the other aggregate (without modifying anything there) - but this approach somehow feels dirty. I would like to just "trust" the commands, because the ID cannot be entered manually but must be selected. The problem is, that our application is a web-application and it is not really safe to trust the user input you get there (even though it is not accessibly by the public).

Did I overlook any possible solutions for this problems or should I just ignore the feeling that there needs to be a better solution?

Comment: Should I assume that the architecture is CQRS based?

Comment: @Constantin Yes you are right. I thought it wouldn't make any difference for my question, so I didn't include it

Comment: @user3841426 it could shape our answers differently, maybe to be richer in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct Aggregate-to-Aggregate interaction is an anti-pattern in DDD. An aggregate A should not directly send a command or query to an aggregate B. Aggregates are strict consistency boundaries.

I can think of 2 solutions to your problem: Let's say you have 2 aggregate roots (AR) - A and B. Each AR has got a bunch of command handlers where each command raises 1 or more events. Your command handler in A depends on some data in B.

1. You can subscribe to the events raised by B and maintain the state of B in A. You can subscribe only to the events which dictate the validity.
2. You can have a completely independent service (S) coordinating between A and B. Instead of directly sending your request to A, send your request to S which would be responsible for a query from B (to check for validity of referenced ID) and then forward request to A. This is sometimes called a Process Manager (PM).

For Example in your case when you are creating a new Entity "Entity1", send this request to a PM whose job would be to validate if the data in your request is valid and then route your request to the aggregate responsible for creating "Entity1". Send a new CreateEntity1Command that contains the ID of the referenced aggregate-root to this PM which uses ID of the referenced AR to make sure it's valid and if it's valid then only it would pass your request forward.

Useful Links: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

Answer (score 7):

Verifying that another referenced Aggregate exists is not the responsibility of an Aggregate. It would break the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). When the `CreateEntity1Command` arrive at the Aggregate, it should be considered that the other referenced Aggregate is in a valid state, i.e. it *exists*.

Being outside the Aggregate's boundary, this checking is eventually consistent. This means that, even if it initially passes, it could become invalid after that (i.e. it is `deleted`, `unpublished` or any other invalid domain state). You need to ensure that:

- the command is rejected, if the referenced Aggregate does not yet exists. You do this checking in the Application service that is responsible for the Use case, before dispatching the command to the Aggregate, using a Domain service.
- if the referenced Aggregate enters an invalid state afterwards, the corrects actions are taken. You should do this inside a Saga/Process manager. If CQRS is used, you subscribe to the relevant events; if not, you use a `cron`. What is the correct action it depends on your domain but the main idea is that it should be modeled as a process.

So, long story short, **the responsibilty of an Aggregate does not extend beyond its consistency boundary**.

*P.S. resist the temptation to inject services (Domain or not) into Aggregates (throught constructor or method arguments).*

Answer (score 0):

> Did I overlook any possible solutions for this problems

You did.  "Domain Services" give you a possible loop hole to play in.

Aggregates are consistency boundaries; their behaviors are constrained by

- The current state of the aggregate
- The arguments that they are passed.

If an aggregate needs to interact with something outside of its boundary, then you pass to the aggregate root a *domain service* to encapsulate that interaction.  The aggregate, at its own discretion, can invoke methods provided by the domain service to achieve work.

Often, the domain service is just a wrapper around an application or infrastructure service.  For instance, if the aggregate needed to know if some external data were available, then you could pass in a domain service that would support that query, checking against some cache of data.

But - here's the trick: you need to stay aware of the fact that data from outside of the aggregate boundary is necessarily *stale*.  There might be another process changing the data even as you are querying a stale copy.

> The problem is, that our application is a web-application and it is not really safe to trust the user input you get there (even though it is not accessibly by the public).

That's true, but it's not typically a domain problem.  For instance, we might specify that an endpoint in our API requires a JSON representation of some command message -- but that doesn't mean that the domain model is responsible for taking a raw byte array and creating a DOM for it.  The application layer would have that responsibility; the aggregate's responsibility is the domain concerns.

It can take some careful thinking to distinguish where the boundary between the different concerns is.  Is this sequence of bytes a *valid* identifier for an aggregate? is clearly an application concerns.  Is the other aggregate in a state that permits some behavior? is clearly a domain concern.  Does the aggregate exist at all...? could go either way.

Comment: > then you pass to the aggregate root a domain service to encapsulate that interaction
This is not correct, and aggregate should operate with its own state and parameters only, never request mutable data sources. Whatever you do that uses domain services, need to be done outside of the aggregate as part of a Saga or Process Manager